# Using boto3 on GAE - getting issue with Popen

Tags: python, google-app-engine, boto3

I am attempting to run some python code in Google App Engine which sends a message to Amazon SQS.

I have installed boto3, but I am getting an error when trying to import it into my AppEngine service:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myservice/test.408770177247417142/lib/botocore/credentials.py", line 763, in ProcessProvider
    def __init__(self, profile_name, load_config, popen=subprocess.Popen):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

Does anyone know how to get boto3 running on GAE? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boto3 doesn't work with app engine because of the app engine sandbox.  Use the latest version of boto2 instead.

I should add that the above is for GAE standard environment.  boto3 might work with GAE flexible.  Please update your question if you need further info.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine has been changed to support boto3 in the Python 2.7 native environment [as of September 24th, 2019](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139956261). However, it still does not support boto3 in the local development server.